# How to detect the value of a host element is binded using in an angular directive

Tags: angular, directive

I am trying to add an attribute to an input field if some text is entered using a custom directive. I am able to do it in on @HostListener('change') event. 
This is perfectly fine for a create page, however in the edit page the data is loaded async and binded via NgModel so i could not find any event to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[testDirective]'
})
export class TestDirective implements AfterViewInit{

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    @HostListener('change') onChange() {
        this.setCustomAttribute();
    }

    @HostListener('input') inputEvent() {
        console.log("i am in input event");
        //input event is not working either
    }

    private setCustomAttribute(){
        if(this.el.nativeElement.value==null||this.el.nativeElement.value==""){
            this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute("custom-attribute", "false");
        }else{
            this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute("custom-attribute", "true")
        } 
    }
}


<input testDirective name="somefield" required  type="text" [(ngModel)]="object.somefield">
```

Comment: Try in `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can inject "NgControl" inside your directive and then attach to valueChanges like this

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[testDirective]'
})
export class TestDirective implements AfterViewInit{



      constructor(private el: ElementRef,private ngControl:NgControl) { 
          this.listenToChanges();
          }




    private listenToChanges(){
               this.ngControl.valueChanges.subscribe(()=>{
                this.setCustomAttribute(); })
           }


    @HostListener('change') onChange() {
        this.setCustomAttribute();
    }

    @HostListener('input') inputEvent() {
        console.log("i am in input event");
        //input event is not working either
    }

    private setCustomAttribute(){
        if(this.el.nativeElement.value==null||this.el.nativeElement.value==""){
            this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute("custom-attribute", "false");
        }else{
            this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute("custom-attribute", "true")
        } 
    }
}


<input testDirective name="somefield" required  type="text" [(ngModel)]="object.somefield">
```

and it will automatically unsubscribe, while directive will be destroyed

Comment: input event is not working when data binded to ngModel, i have updated my question accordingly

Comment: if you have ngModel you could inject NgControl to your directive constructor and subscribe to valueChanges event

Comment: thanks for the reply, your solution works. Can you please elaborate your answer? what did i subscribe to exactly and should i unsubscribe when i change the page ? @onik

Answer (score 0):

try ngAfterViewInit method

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   if(this.el.nativeElement.value==null||this.el.nativeElement.value==""){
        this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute("custom-attribute", "false");
    }else{
        this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute("custom-attribute", "true")
    } 
}
```

Comment: hello, i have tried this, but data may as well be loaded after ngAfterViewInit method if the server is slow